# MS Access Text Search Box with referenced values

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Lets assume I have 2 tables: Projects and Employees. Each project got one responsible employee that I chose as a Lookup Value from the Employee table.

Now I understand that Access saves the ID of the employee in the project table and that's good. However, now I want to create a search query to get all projects with e.g. Mike as responsible person.

This is my code:

```
SELECT projects.name, projects.responsible
FROM projects
WHERE projects.responsible = Forms!form_search!employee_name;
```

Now it works fine if I type in the Form the employee ID but I cannot remember all IDs. I want to be able to type in 'Mike' in the Form and the query delivers me still all of Mike's projects.

How can I achieve that?

I thought about something like:

```
WHERE (projects.responsible = (employees.ID WHERE employees.name = Forms...));
```

But this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dropdown list with 2 columns as a filter criteria.

To fill this list, you make a request on your employee table, hide the first column (0cm wide) and the second column would display the matching employee name but your SQL request still receive the ID as criteria.

You should NOT have to modify your SQL request.